# Separate complete and incomplete rows from dataset in pandas and python

Tags: pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning, imputation

How can I separate complete and incomplete rows in a dataset in pandas and python (I need to separate them to get a test and training model for imputation)? 
and after imputation how can I place that imputed rows at it's original index?

Comment: What's your definition of 'complete' and 'incomplete' rows? Is it with and without missing values?

Comment: yes, I need to separate dataset (Rows) with missing values from non-missing values(rows).

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of the functions notnull() and dropna() for this

```
    #creating a dummy dataset
    s=[1,2,3,4,np.NAN,5]
    s1=[1,2,np.NAN,np.NAN,3,4]
    s2=[1,2,3,np.NAN,np.NAN,np.NAN]
    df=pd.DataFrame({'r1':s,'r2':s1,'r3':s2})
    #reset_index will add a column index for future concatenation
    df=df.reset_index()

    #getting the rows without null values
    not_nulls=df.dropna()

    #getting only the rows with null values
    nulls=df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

    #fill the null values using the required logic, Here im just filling with zero
    nulls=nulls.fillna(0)

    #combining not null and filled null rows
    combined=pd.concat([nulls,not_nulls])
    #sorting to get in the original order
    combined=combined.sort_values(by='index')
```